# $I=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos^2 \alpha x }{1+x^2}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I have to find 
$$I(\alpha)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos^2 \alpha x }{1+x^2}\,dx.$$ 
Can someone help me to solve it?

Answer (score 8):

$$ I(\alpha) = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{1+x^2}+\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(2\alpha x)}{1+x^2}\,dx =\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{1}{2}\,J(2\alpha)$$
where:
$$ J(\beta) = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(\beta x)}{1+x^2}\,dx$$
fulfills $J(0)=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and, assuming $\beta>0$, 
$$ J'(\beta) = -\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x\sin(\beta x)}{1+x^2}\,dx = -J(\beta)$$
by integration by parts. It follows that $J(\beta)=\frac{\pi}{2} e^{-\beta}$ and

> $$ I(\alpha) = \color{red}{\frac{\pi}{4}\left(1+e^{-2|\alpha|}\right)}.$$

Comment: I think there is a $dx$ missing in second integral.

Comment: @MrYouMath: thank you,now fixed.

Comment: why $$J'(\beta) = -\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x\sin(\beta x)}{1+x^2}\,dx = -J(\beta)\,.$$

Comment: @Tuanlee: even easier than integration by parts: what is $J''(\beta)$? That leaves a second-order DE, having $\frac{\pi}{2}e^{\pm \beta}$ as solutions. But since $\lim_{\beta\to +\infty}J(\beta)=0$, we have to take the solution with the negative exponent.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
{\rm I}\pars{\alpha} & =
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\cos^{2}\pars{\alpha x} \over x^{2} + 1}\,\dd x =
\half\ \overbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd x \over x^{2} + 1}}^{\ds{=\ \pi/2}}\ +\
\half\int_{0}^{\infty}{\cos\pars{2\verts{\alpha}x} \over x^{2} + 1}\,\dd x
\\[3mm] & =
{\pi \over 4} + {1 \over 4}\,\Re\color{#00f}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\expo{2\verts{\alpha}x\ic} \over \pars{x + \ic}\pars{x - \ic}}\,\dd x} =
{\pi \over 4} + {1 \over 4}\,\Re\pars{2\pi\ic\,{\expo{2\verts{\alpha}\pars{\ic}\ic} \over \ic + \ic}}
\\[3mm] & = \fbox{$\ds{{\pi \over 4}\pars{1 + \expo{-2\verts{\alpha}}}}$}
\end{align}

The $\color{#00f}{\mbox{blue}}$ integral is evaluated by Residues Theorem with a semicircle in the upper complex plane.

Comment: (+1) Long time no see, I am glad you are back.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I was somehow very busy. Thanks.

Comment: @Tuanlee Thanks. You're welcome.